# Regex to load integer number of "key value" pairs e.g. 3 key1 "value1" key2 "value2" key3 "value3"

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to create a regex to parse a line which contains an integer number of values following an integer, can get it mostly working but not for the case when there the integer is zero and no values following.

e.g.

```
..... 2 "value1" "value2" "someother non-related text"
..... 0 "someother non-related text"
```

Also an integer number of space-separated key value pairs following the integer number or

```
..... 3 key1 "value1" key2 "value2" key3 "value3"......
```

Happy to stuff them in a single named group but might be useful at a later date to have them in separate named groups.

```
3 "value1" "value2" "value3" "someother non-related text"

(?<my_named_group>([0])|[0-9] (?<my_values>(".*"?)?))

my_named_group = 3
my_values = '"value1" "value2" "value3"'
```

and when the integer is zero

```
my_named_group = 0
my_values = ""
```

and for the second question/regex

```
3 key1 "value1" key2 "value2" key3 "value3" "someother non-related text"

my_named_group = 3
my_values = 'key 1 "value1" key 2 "value2" key3 "value3"'
```

Comment: What if you try `(?<my_named_group>[0-9]+)\s+"(?<my_values>.*)"`? See https://regex101.com/r/C9M1HN/1

Comment: What exactly do you want to match when it starts with zero? And if it is not zero, do you want to match the whole line or 3 and `"value1" "value2" "value3"`

Comment: only the 3 values which follow, nothing after in this expression

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, we are having digits followed by some texts in quotes, and we can likely start solving it using a simple expression:

```
([0-9]+).+?(\".*\")
```

where are desired digits are in the first capturing group `([0-9]+)` and the other desired substring is in the second one, `(\".*\")`.

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([0-9]+).+?(\".*\")"

test_str = ("2 \"value1\" \"value2\" \"someother non-related text\"\n"
    "0 \"someother non-related text\"\n"
    "3 key1 \"value1\" key2 \"value2\" key3 \"value3\"")

subst = "\\1\\n\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aDolT5/1)

Comment: That is correct emma, two totally separate regex's should have stated more clearly. When the integer is 0 i do not want to match anything, when the integer is positive e.g 3 i want to match the next 3 values, not the 4th.

Comment: and the second is similar but more complicated, if the integer is 0, i do not want to match any key value pairs (space-separated), but if its e.g. 3 i expect to match 3 key value pairs (space-separated)

Comment: however, there will be fields i.e. "some other non-related text" that follow both of these regexs which should not be matched, hopefully as clear as mud now